# My JQuery Datepicker doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've made a php page (something about hotel reservation) and I want to make a JQuery Datepicker, I have tried this on a blank page, provided the needed css and js files, and it works.

But when I tried it on my customized page, it doesn't work. I think it's something that has to do with the other css and / or other javascript files in my page, but I removed them for testing. But still sadly it doesn't appear.. What seems to be the problem?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reservationsCSS.css" />
            <link href = "css/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
            <?php include 'includes/head.inc.php'; ?>

    <!-- Datepicker JavaScript function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $( "#checkInDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy", minDate: 0}).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
        $( "#checkOutDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy", minDate: 0}).datepicker("setDate",+1);
     });
  </script>
</head>

<body id="top">
    <!-----navbar-section------>
    <header class = "container">
        <?php include 'includes/navbar.inc.php'; ?>
    </header>
    <!-----navbar-section------>

            <section id="banner">
                <div class="inner">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Reservation</h1>
                        <h2>Please enter your arrival and departure date.</h2>
                        <p></p>
                    </header>
                </div>
            </section>

        <!-- Main -->
            <div id="main">
                <div class="inner">
                    <form action = "datepickerProcess.php" method = "POST">
                        <p>Check-in Date: <input type = "text" id = "checkInDate" name = "checkInDate"></p> <br>
                        <p>Check-out Date: <input type = "text" id = "checkOutDate" name = "checkOutDate"></p> <br>
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Go to Rooms >">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
            <footer id="footer">
                <?php include 'includes/footer.inc.php';?>
            </footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
        <!-- <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: I'm sorry, what console? It doesn't show any error in php by the way. But when I click the textbox the JQuery datepicker doesn't appear.

Comment: in ie, press f-12.   it will have a console and it should stop on the first error.  Your dates not appearing can be a side effect of other issues

Comment: JS script do not show on browser window, it is shown on console of browser

Comment: It seems your code for datepicker works. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ectk39c2/)

Comment: side note: use `require_once()` instead of `include()` whenever possible, as former one will emit PHP Error and stop further processing the rest of the codes, while the latter one will continue.

Comment: I see the console now. I didn't know that until now. Thank you very much!

@MayankPandeyz
@Bindrid

It says: 

`reservationPage1.php:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ reservationPage1.php:19`

Line 19 starts from:
`<header class = "container">`

Comment: I think you have not included the jquery library in your code

Comment: Console is the most important section of browser for developer, here you can check ajax call, html dom, js errors, and you can dynamically change css and dom also

Comment: Move your Datepicker JavaScript function below jquery reference at the bottom of your html code. Then only jQuery/$ will be defined in JS context

Comment: @MayankPandeyz thank you for that information! I didn't know that until now =)

Comment: @Raptor thank you for that information! I used `include` because I saw it in a codecourse video tutorial, when you have `link rel` and other repetitive codes, the author just put it in another .php file and include it in his other pages. Thank, I learned something new :)

Comment: Explore the console, it have so much for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add

```
<!-- Datepicker JavaScript function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $( "#checkInDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy", minDate: 0}).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
        $( "#checkOutDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy", minDate: 0}).datepicker("setDate",+1);
     });
  </script>
```

after the jquery imports of your page
it should work fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes, I tried to change and add the custom script below the jQuery imports. It worked! Thank you!